# Is "farewell reception" correct?

Tags: word-choice

I was recently invited to a "farewell reception," a gathering to celebrate a couple who are soon leaving the community. And it occurred to me that "farewell reception" is an oxymoron.

Is "reception" used correctly here. Is there a better word?

Comment: It is a good word.  It's an occasion where guests are *received*.

Comment: -1; In all seriousness, why would this be an oxymoron?

Comment: @MrHen Probably because *reception* in most dictionaries is *greeting someone*. Combining it with *farewell* may seem awkward.

Comment: @Philoto: Here they are two nouns, right? Usually an oxymoron works with a modifier, not two nouns. I'm not totally sure of that, though.

Comment: @Alenanno *Farewell* can be an adjective, but I really don't know which one it is here. That was just a thought :)

Comment: @Alenanno A *noun* can be a *noun modifier* in English (*attributive noun*). This is an example of one.

Comment: +1 @MrHen, I don't think that a clear question should be voted down no matter how obvious the answer seem to you.

Comment: @Unreason I don't think you should vote based on other peoples' votes, just whether *you* think it is a good question.

Comment: @z7sg, on other so sites even that is rather common; however in this instance I actually did like it. I opened http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/correcting-a-down-vote-of-the-question if there is more to discuss

Comment: @Unreason: I downvoted because I felt it was "not useful" and "did not show any research", both of which are listed as reasons in the hover text on the button. I also voted to close as General Reference.

Comment: @MrHen, I really respect your opinion, but still don't agree with it. Here are my reasons: 1) on "not useful" this with language is really problematic as you could almost always find someone not knowing something (in this case one half of primary meaning of the word) 2) on did not show any reasearch - actually guidelines mention not general research, but searching the EL&U(!, follow the link). I take this to mean that even the most basic question should be welcome, *if* they are not duplicates. As for close, I have no objections. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reception" is a perfectly valid word here; the hosts are *receiving visitors* still.  The purpose of the reception is a separate matter.

Alternatively you could say "farewell gathering" or "farewell party" depending on just what would be happening.  If you were feeling particularly fancy you could call it a "valediction party", and you might get away with just a "[valediction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valediction)" though that's stretching the meaning of the word a little.

Comment: Thanks. I had always thought a reception was intended to welcome (receive) someone new, like a wedding reception receiving a new couple. Receiving the guests makes sense too.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/reception?show=0&t=1307543645) reception is

> a social gathering

or, to be more precise

> a formal party for guests, such as one after a wedding

form [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reception)

Neither [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/reception) nor [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reception) agree with this definition

Personally, I'm pretty sure, that in formal speech *reception* is indeed used as a synonym to *meeting* or *gathering*. In informal speech most probably I would've used "farewell party"

Answer (score 1):

The first meaning listed in macmillan for [reception](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reception#reception_16) is

> a formal party to welcome someone or to celebrate something

(Sense of "ceremonial gathering" is 1882, from French.)

so a *farewell reception* would be an oxymoron if the meaning was only to welcome. In this case it is logical to assume the second meaning: a "formal party" at which you celebrate someone's departure and wish them farewell.

Farewell as [adjective](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/farewell_10#farewell_13)

> done in order to celebrate the fact that someone is leaving a place or job